# Error Running Flutter App on iOS after moving to M1 Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I recently moved my projects to my M1 MacBook Pro. But I get the following error when running `flutter run` on iPhone 12 Pro Max Simulator.

````
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

    ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE
    ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    ### Command

    ```
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod install --verbose
    ```

    ### Report

    * What did you do?

    * What did you expect to happen?

    * What happened instead?


    ### Stack

    ```
       CocoaPods : 1.10.1
            Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)
            [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
        RubyGems : 3.0.3
            Host : macOS 11.1 (20C69)
           Xcode : 12.3 (12C33)
             Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
    Ruby lib dir :
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
    Repositories : 
    ```

    ### Plugins

    ```
    cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
    cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
    cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
    ```

    ### Podfile

    ```ruby
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '9.0'

    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter
    build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }

    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..',
      'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're
        running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed
        first"
      end

      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}.
      Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end

    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin',
    'podhelper'), flutter_root)

    flutter_ios_podfile_setup

    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!

      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end

    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
    ```

    ### Error

    ```
    LoadError - dlsym(0x7f84b630ab40, Init_ffi_c): symbol not found -
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top
    (required)>'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.12.0/lib/ethon.rb:2:in `<top
    (required)>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top
    (required)>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/ru
    bygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/sources_manager.rb:74:in `cdn_url?'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/sources_manager.rb:36:in `create_source_with_url'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/sources_manager.rb:21:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer/analyzer.rb:1073:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
    `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/coco
    apods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:
    55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    ```
    Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target
    `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for
    this target in your Podfile. See
    `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
````

I tried creating a new flutter app and running it and it worked well, but when I added my dependencies to `pubspec.yaml` it again showed the same error.

My dependency list

- intl: ^0.16.1
- firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
- firebase_analytics: ^6.0.2
- firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.1+1
- firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2
- firebase_database: ^4.1.1
- firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
- cloud_firestore: ^0.14.1+3
- firebase_storage: ^4.0.1
- firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.7
- firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.6.0+2
- firebase_remote_config: ^0.4.0+2
- readmore: ^1.0.0
- like_button: ^1.0.1
- timeago: ^2.0.26
- eyro_toast: ^0.1.0
- quick_actions: ^0.4.0+10
- vibration: ^1.4.0
- receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.0+2
- cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
- full_screen_image: ^1.0.2
- flutter_native_image: ^0.0.5+2
- image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
- image_cropper: ^1.2.3
- flutter_blurhash: ^0.5.0
- linkify: ^2.1.0
- liquid_progress_indicator: ^0.3.2
- material_tag_editor: ^0.0.2
- carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
- liquid_pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
- animated_splash_screen: ^1.0.0+1
- expandable: ^4.1.4
- flutter_linkify: ^3.1.3
- flutter_parsed_text: ^1.2.4
- url_launcher: ^5.5.0
- octo_image: ^0.2.1
- smooth_page_indicator: ^0.2.0
- shimmer: ^1.1.1
- pagination_view: ^1.0.3+2
- scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.1.7
- geocoder: ^0.2.1
- location: ^3.0.2
- inview_notifier_list: ^1.0.0
- share: ^0.6.5+2
- visibility_detector: ^0.1.5
- animations: ^1.1.2
- native_state: ^1.1.1
- story_view: ^0.12.3
- file_picker: ^1.13.3
- mime: ^0.9.7
- flutter_colorpicker: ^0.3.4
- video_player: ^0.10.12+2
- dotted_border: ^1.0.6
- step_progress_indicator: ^0.2.4+7
- timer_count_down: ^1.0.4+1
- flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.2
- flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+4
- app_settings: ^4.0.4
- flutter_svg: ^0.19.0
- flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7
- preload_page_view: ^0.1.4
- custom_navigation_bar: ^0.3.2
- page_transition: ^1.1.7+2
- cube_transition: ^1.0.2
- provider: ^4.3.2+2
- delayed_display: ^1.0.3
- supercharged: ^1.10.0
- image: ^2.1.18
- path_provider: ^1.6.18
- meta: ^1.1.6
- bitmap: ^0.0.6
- numberpicker: ^1.2.1
- image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.0
- permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
- dio: ^3.0.10
- device_preview: ^0.4.8
- image_editor: ^0.7.3
- extended_image: ^1.3.0
- flutter_credit_card: ^0.1.3
- stripe_payment: ^1.0.8
- charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
- flutter_native_admob: ^2.1.0+3
- mask_text_input_formatter: ^1.1.0
- shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
- flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
- introduction_screen: ^1.0.9
- property_change_notifier: ^0.2.0
- screenshot: ^0.2.0
- auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
- responsive_flutter: ^0.0.4
- cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

Run on ***MacBook Pro*** (***M1***)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install `ffi` dependency manually. Here is the same issue on GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70796. Also, if you have troubles with build or run you app on M1, visit to [Wiki page on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Developing-with-Flutter-on-Apple-Silicon) with usage guide and [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60118) for tracking current support phase for new macs.